# Changing an instance variable in a block

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings, block, ivar

I am quite confused about how to change an instance variable inside of a block.

The interface file (.h):

```
@interface TPFavoritesViewController : UIViewController {
    bool refreshing;
}
```

The implementation:

```
__weak TPFavoritesViewController *temp_self = self;
refreshing = NO;
[myTableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
    refreshing = YES;
    [temp_self refresh];
}];
```

As you might guess, I get a retain cycle warning when I try to change the refreshing ivar inside of the block. How would I do this without getting an error?

Answer (score 6):

Your assignment to `refreshing` is an implicit reference to `self`, it is shorthand for:

```
self->refreshing = YES;
```

hence the cycle warning. Change it to:

```
temp_self->refreshing = YES;
```

Comment: It doesn't build with only this code. I get the following error: Dereferencing a __weak is not allowed due to possible null value caused by a race condition, assign it to a strong variable first. I think I got it working by adding this: __strong TPRideListView *strong_self = temp_self;
strong_self->refreshing = YES;

Comment: Careful; dereferencing a weak pointer can lead to crashes. Better to make a strong pointer from the weak one inside the block, check for nil, and use that.

Comment: @KeiranPaster - apologies I missed the second warning; if your code keeps the warnings at bay its fine, you have it working *provided* your object is staying around (i.e. `self` is valid); the code does not deal with the possibility of a `nil` value. I assume you know it is, if you don't...